# React no actualiza estado con useEffect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, useeffect

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?
Quiero hacer un InputSelect que tenga opciones de filtrado/ordenación de un listado de vídeos. Os dejo código y explico un poco:

VideoList.tsx

```
interface IVideo {
  created: string;
  duration: number;
}

interface VideoListProps {
  title: string;
  videos: IVideo[];
}

const VideoList = ({ title, videos }: VideoListProps) => {
  const [filterSelected, setFilterSelected] = useState<string>("");
  const [sortedVideos, setSortedVideos] = useState<IVideo[]>([]);

  let { t } = useTranslation();

  const options = [
    "Por duración - decreciente"
  ];

  const sortByFilter = (filter: string, videos: IVideo[]): IVideo[] => {
    switch (filter) {
      case "Por duración - decreciente":
        return videos.sort((a, b) => a.duration + b.duration);
      default:
        return videos;
    }
  };

  const handleFilterChange = (e: any) => {
    setFilterSelected(e.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setSortedVideos(sortByFilter(filterSelected, videos));
  }, [filterSelected]);

  return (
    <>
      <h4>{title}</h4>
      <section className={styles.videolist_section}>
        <InputSelect
          name={"filter"}
          title={"Ordenar por"}
          label={t("masterclass:filter_selection_title")}
          options={options}
          defaultSelected={options[0]}
          onChange={handleFilterChange}
          optional={true}
        />
        <h3>{filterSelected}</h3>
        {sortedVideos.length > 0
          ? sortedVideos.map((video) => {
              return <h1>{video.duration}</h1>;
            })
          : videos.map((video) => {
              <h3>{video.duration}</h3>;
            })}

      </section>
    </>
  );
};

export default VideoList;
```

Lo que hago es básicamente tener un componente InputSelect que es el Input con las opciones en cuestión, el cual cuando cambia actualiza el estado filterSelected.

Cada vez que cambia este estado, mediante el useEffect actualizo la lista de videos ordenados almacenados en sortedVideos, dependiendo del filtro escogido, mediante la función sortByFilter, que recide como parámetros el filtro seleccionado (que proviene del estado del componente) y la lista de vídeos a ordenar. El caso es que estoy probando a filtrar por duración pero no lo hace, ni actualiza correctamente el estado sortedVideos.

Como renderizado tengo una condicional que si hay vídeos ordenados los muestra y sino muestra la lista de vídeo original que llega por props.

La lista de vídeos original es:

```
{ created: "", duration: 0 },
      { created: "", duration: 2 },
      { created: "", duration: 1 }
```

Y al aplicar el filtro se ve que no ordena ni se modifica correctamente el estado sortedVideos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No estoy seguro sea exactamente por eso pero tiene toda la pinta. Cuando haces `return videos.sort` estás retornando una referencia al mismo array original, por tanto, en `setSortedVideos(sortByFilter...)` estás seteando el estado al mismo objeto original, y puede que por ello react no te detecte el cambio de estado. Prueba algo cómo: `return [...videos.sort(// tu funcion flecha)]` para devolver un nuevo array en lugar de modificar el original.

Comment: Si, era eso, me ha funcionado de maravilla, gracias!

Comment: Pero sigue sin funcionar, es decir, los arrays me los devuelve bien pero no los ordena, ¿puede ser que el useEffect ese ejecute antes de que se actualize el estado filterSelected?

Comment: No entendí si te funcionó o no, porque tus dos comentarios se contradicen, pero bueno. Para quitarse la duda del useEffect ¿Por qué no pones el `setSortedVideos(sortByFilter(filterSelected, videos));` dentro del `handleFilterChange`? No veo por que tener un usseEffect para ello. Elimina el useEffect y prueba.

Comment: Acabo de hacerlo y nada, no consigo que renderice el resultado, es más, el sort no funciona correctamente cuando es una ordenación muy sencilla, y los estados tampoco se actualizan bien.. no consigo entender qué falla

Comment: Por otro lado, en cuanto al `sort`. Si quieres ordenar ascendente usa `a.duration - b.duration` y si quieres ordenar descendente usa `b.duration - a.duration`. No se ese `+` que función cumple ahí. Eso es otra cosa que está incorrecta.